# C++/Qt signals and dynamic memory operation

Tags: c++, qt, struct, memory-management

I am a new user in C++ object-oriented programming and Qt GUI framework. Now I got a very strange error for me, I hope someone can help one out.

In the hearder of the main window I created a struct with three fields:

```
struct structForDataReceiving {
    char *imageDataAll;
    int *index;
    qint64 *TimeStamp;
}
```

In the header file of the main window, I create an struct like this:

```
structForDataReceiving ImageSpaceInMemory;
```

Before receiving the data, in the main window I allocate memory like this:

```
ImageSpaceInMemory.imageDataAll = new char [totalMemorySize];
ImageSpaceInMemory.TStampSec = new qint64 [totalFrames * 2];
ImageSpaceInMemory.imageIndex = new int [totalFrames];
```

From an independent threads, there are two signals to send the data to the slots in the main window:

```
void emitCameraFrameFinished(int number, int ki, char* pData, int XSize, int YSize, int Zsize);
void emitCameraFrameTimeStamp(int number, unsigned long *TStampSec, long *TStampMicro, int idx);
```

I connect these signals with two slots in the main window.
This part works fine.

In one slot of the main window, let's say slot 1, I do:

```
std::memcpy(ImageSpaceInMemory.imageDataAll + offset, pData, size);
```

it works well, receiving data is smooth.

In another slot, let's say slot 2, I do

```
qint64 *datePtr;
datePtr = ImageSpaceInMemory.TStampSec;
datePtr[k*2] = static_cast<qint64>(TStampSec[idx]); // TStampSec[idx];
datePtr[k*2+1] = TStampMicro[idx];
```

It also works well.

However, if I try to do a second operation with the struct in slot 1:

```
std::memcpy(ImageSpaceInMemory.imageDataAll + offset, pData, size);

int *imageIndexPtr;
imageIndexPtr = ImageSpaceInMemory.imageIndex;
imageIndexPtr[k] = static_cast<int>(ki);
```

The program will crash immediately.

I just don't understand, in slot 2 this method works well, and in slot 1 the memcpy also works well. Why does the last try do not work at all?
As a new user, I do not know better memory model/method that can handle this problem better. If you know it, I deeply appreciate it if you can share it.

Another point is, I need to pre-allocate memory before receiving the data from a child thread.

Could someone help me out?

Comment: We can't really tell without knowing all essential parts of your program - so please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You are probably exceeding the allocated memory

Comment: Just a general comment: you write you are a beginner in C++ (I guess your previous language was C). Then I recommend you should benefit from RAII. Create classes which would wrap your raw pointers into classes which then take care of all correct allocations and deallocations. It will help you get rid of most of errors related to wrong pointer management. With good C++ code you almost never have to write `new` and `delete`. Plus you should learn about smart pointer `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

Christian-Ehrlicher in Qt forum has suggested to use C++ containers. Thank you Christian-Ehrlicher, for your great effort. The C++ container method (std::vector index) to create independent vector after the struct initialization, which solved my problem perfectly. Now the code looks like this:

```
structForDataReceiving ImageSpaceInMemory;
std::vector<int> imageIndex;
```

Thank you all for giving me the hints about how to use C++ correctly.

Yes, normally I use C rather than C++. I learned C in my university time by self-education, but I have never learned C++.

Normally as a biologist, C-style programming, e.g. mex in MatLab and CUDA combined with mex are enough for me to do my calculations.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).